# how to count the total without NA

Tags: r

I want to do a summary count by group. And I don't want the final results include the calculation of 'NA'. I used the codes like following:

```
Outcome <- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>% summarise(Outcome_Count = n(),na.rm=TRUE)
```

But it did not exclude `NA`, instead it add a var `na.rm`.
It looks like this:
[image]

What should I do now in order to get Outcome without last row? I still want the one for UNKNOWn. It means differently compared to the case with `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this filtering out `NA` from your key variable:

```
#Code
Outcome <- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
  filter(!is.na(AEOUT)) %>%
  summarise(Outcome_Count = n())
```

Comment: Yes. This could work. Silly me. Only thinking about limit it within `summarise`. Is it a way to do similar thing within `summarise`?

Comment: @Stataq If you would have a function like sum, mean, etc, you can use `na.rm` otherwise you could use `na.omit`, but is more practical filtering first to avoid other potential issues. Hope that helps you!